# pandas fill missing value with median given group

Tags: pandas, group-by, missing-data

I have a data set with 100+ columns and half million rows. For column `Z`, some of the values are missing. I am going to first group the data by 2 columns `(A,B)`, then for each group, I get the median (skip those nans), then I want to fill the nans in `Z` by those median for the corresponding group.

I could

```
df.groupby(["A","B"]).Z.median()
```

But it also has nans in some of the group and I am not sure how to proceed to really fill those nans in `Z` by the group median...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(["A","B"]).Z.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
```